# How To embed Matplotlib plot in a Pyglet window

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyglet

I'm just starting to use pyglet, and I'm trying to develop a visual rendering for a reinforcement learning application using gym.

I would need to integrate a graph generated with matplolib or something else to my window. I found some sample code that does what I want, but it doesn't seem to work since python 3.

There seems to be a problem with the StringIO class of io that I declare at line 15 and use at line 16. I'am not sure of what it is exactly though.

```
import pyglet
import io
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg


def render_figure(fig):
    w, h = fig.get_size_inches()
    dpi_res = fig.get_dpi()
    w, h = int(np.ceil(w * dpi_res)), int(np.ceil(h * dpi_res))

    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    pic_data = io.StringIO()
    canvas.print_raw(pic_data, dpi=dpi_res)
    return pyglet.image.ImageData(w, h, "RGBA", pic_data.getvalue(), -4 * w)


def draw_figure(fig):
    X = np.linspace(-6, 6, 1024)
    Y = np.sinc(X)

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(X, Y, lw=2, color="k")


window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True)
dpi_res = min(window.width, window.height) / 10
fig = Figure((window.width / dpi_res, window.height / dpi_res), dpi=dpi_res)

draw_figure(fig)
image = render_figure(fig)


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    image.blit(0, 0)


pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [`FigureCanvasAgg.print_to_buffer()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.print_to_buffer) method:

```py
def render_figure(fig):
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    data, (w, h) = canvas.print_to_buffer()
    return pyglet.image.ImageData(w, h, "RGBA", data, -4 * w)
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked, thanks

Comment: @PhilippeMaisonneuve Please review the [tour]